# combinations $\sum_{k=1}^m kn_k=m!$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If $n_k$'s are non-negative integers, how many ways can we solve
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m kn_k=m!.
$$

I don't even know if the answer can be written in a nice form (as a function of $m$). Any suggestions or references would help.

Comment: Do you mean $n^k$ ?

Comment: No, I mean $n_k$.

Comment: What is $n_k$? That's not a notation I'm familiar with if it is some function of $n$ and $k$.

Comment: @Mitch: e.g.: $n_1+2n_2+3n_3=3!$

Comment: So, to put into words, you're trying to find the integer partitions of $m!$ into $m$ parts?

Comment: @Mitch: rather integer partitions of m! into parts at most m: multiplicity of part 0<=k<=m is requestor's n_k.

Comment: Just to be clear, for example, if $m = 4$ you'd like the number of solutions of $24 = n_1 + 2 n_2 + 3 n_3 + 4 n_4$ ?

Comment: See here for more terms and references: https://oeis.org/A236810

Comment: I didn't understand the $nk$ notation but I guess I solved recently [something similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/668702/85343) which is not very easy.

Comment: @Mitch: yes, number of solutions with $n_i\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is http://oeis.org/A008290:  rencontres numbers (number of permutations of n elements with k fixed points) with the first column dropped :
{1},
{0, 1},
{3, 0, 1},
{8, 6, 0, 1},
{45, 20, 10, 0, 1},
{264, 135, 40, 15, 0, 1},
{1855, 924, 315, 70, 21, 0, 1}
Generally, you ask to split m! into m terms, the k'th term being a multiple of k.
So, use generating function 
prod(k=1..m; 1/(1-x^k) ) and get the coefficient of x^(m!) ;
this gives the sequence  1, 2, 7, 169, 91606, 2407275335, 4592460368601183, ...
Restricting to positive coefficients n_k we find
using prod(k=1..m; x^k/(1-x^k) ) and taking the coefficient of x^(m!) again:
1, 0, 1, 47, 55496, 2080571733, 4441900888487987